# How can I add Heat to Ubuntu OpenStack single-machine environment?

Tags: software-installation, openstack

I have installed OpenStack on a single machine using Ubuntu `openstack-installer` and everything worked. (Juno on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

I would now like to add the Orchestration service (Heat), but I
am a bit confused by that container environment. What would be
the general approach to take? I know where to find the procedure
for a manual install, but I'm just not too sure where to start 
with this container environment.

Answer (score 0):

Our experimental ppa contains a plugin for heat that you can access via the `add unit dialog` (keypress 'A'). If using our stable package you can do the following to add heat to your stack:

```
# Obtain the container name
sudo lxc-ls

# Attach to container
sudo lxc-attach <name>

# become ubuntu user and set JUJU_HOME
sudo su - ubuntu
export JUJU_HOME=/home/ubuntu/.cloud-install/juju

# Add heat
juju deploy heat
```